# Adding distance matrix to google direction

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

Help me with google direction to include distance matrix

on my site, im using the below code to get Google map. what code should i add to also show distance between from and to and also traveling time?

thank you.

```
<div style="width: 298px;">
 <div id="map" style="width: 298px; height: 400px; float: left;"></div>
```

```
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom:7,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

 var request = {
   origin: '<?php echo $contents['pickupname']; ?>', 
   destination: '<?php echo $contents['dropoffname']; ?>',
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };

 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   }

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Make this changes:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}   

 var myRoute = response.routes[0].legs[0];
 var duration = myRoute.duration.value;
 var distance = myRoute.distance.value;   
});
```

Also note this code is just for demonstration. You need to modify the code to check cases where there are multiple routes, legs.
For detailed information see [DirectionsResult](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsResult), [DirectionsRoute](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsRoute), [DirectionsLeg](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsLeg)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I'm using:

First add element that will show your data in HTML. I'm using input element like this:

```
<input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
```

When you do the calculation in you JS send that data to input. For example:

```
var distanceInput = document.getElementById('distance');
distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
```